# Calculation of integral around circle

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I had the equation$$\int(xdy-ydx)$$around the circle
$$x^2+y^2=1$$
I tried this:
$$\begin{align}x&=(1-y^2)^{1/2}\\y&=(1-x^2)^{1/2}\end{align}$$
$$\int(1-y^2)^{1/2}dy-\int(1-x^2)^{1/2}dx=0$$
The limits of both $x$ and $y$ are same so both should cancel out and give ans$= 0$
but the answer is $2\pi$.

Comment: The photos are not readable. Please try submitting something clearer

Comment: uploaded new images @marlasca23

Answer (score 2):

I don't know whether you took the correct Cartesian limits, but it's more convenient to work in polar coordinates. Since the circle is $r=1$,$$xdy-ydx=\cos\theta\cdot\cos\theta d\theta-\sin\theta(-\sin\theta)d\theta=d\theta.$$Now it's obvious the answer is $2\pi$.

Comment: my assumed Limits for x and y are (-1,1)
As in this circle radius is 1 and center of circle is also (0,0)

Comment: @SagarSingh Well, that's where you went wrong. For example, the bounds on $x$ are $\pm\sqrt{1-y^2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively we can use Green's theorem:  $$\int_C Pdx + Qdy=\int_D(Q_x-P_y)dA$$
where C is a simple closed curve, D is the area bounded by C.  In your integral, we have $$P=-y$$, $$Q=x$$, C is the unit circle, D is the unit disk. So $$P_y=-1$$$$Q_x=1$$
and our integral switches to just
$$\int_D(1-(-1))dA$$
and since the area of the unit circle is $\pi$,  there you go.